# Sequence of Gamma r.v.s converges in probability to 1

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a squence of Gamma distributed random variables with pdf

$$
 f(x;\alpha,\beta) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill \dfrac{x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x/\beta}}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}    \hfill & \text{ for $x>0$} \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{elsewhere} \\
  \end{cases}
$$
In our case, we have $\alpha = n$ and $\beta = 1/n$. Show that
$$X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to} 1$$

My try: We have to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$:
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n - 1|<\varepsilon)=\mathbb{P}(-1+\varepsilon < X_n < 1-\varepsilon)=1$$
Thus:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(-1+\varepsilon < X_n < 1-\varepsilon) &= \int_{-1+\varepsilon}^{1-\varepsilon} f(x;n,1/n)\mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_{0}^{1-\varepsilon}\dfrac{x^{n - 1}e^{-nx}}{\dfrac{1}{n^n}\Gamma(n)}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\dfrac{n^n}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{0}^{1-\varepsilon} x^{n - 1}e^{-nx}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
Now make the substitution $x \mapsto nx$, this yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(-1+\varepsilon < X_n < 1-\varepsilon) &= \dfrac{n^n}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{0}^{n(1-\varepsilon)} \dfrac{1}{n}\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^{n - 1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x \\ 
&= \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{0}^{n(1-\varepsilon)} x^{n - 1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
Now, taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we yield

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(-1+\varepsilon < X_n < 1-\varepsilon) &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^{n(1-\varepsilon)} x^{n - 1}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n)} \\
&=1
\end{align*}
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was given arbitrarily, we conclude that
$$X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to} 1$$
And I think I solved my question...

For the sake of future reference or if someone has the same (kind of) problem, I will post it anyways, even tough I am pretty sure I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an error:  $$|X_n - 1| < \epsilon \quad \iff \quad 1-\epsilon < X_n < 1+\epsilon.$$

Comment: You are correct, but that does not change my answer, does it? I just have to adjust some bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Some years later, hehe. I consider that approach is kind of complicated. I'd use the fact that $E[X_n] = 1$, so we can try to calculate $P(|X_n - \mu| \geqslant \epsilon)$, use Chebyshev's theorem and then use the squeeze theorem to conclude that $X_n \overset{P}\to  \mu = 1$.